# How To attach Automated Events to jquery cloned elements which classes are auto incremented

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, clone

I am building a itirnary bilder where when i click add day one form appear with three button those three buttons also containe separated attached forms on click, i can clone successfuly add event listner also by .on method but my issue is end user may submit 100 forms using add new button so i need a trick to auto attach events to incremented classes as i incremented classes automatically in my program. (notice that budget accomdation transist buttons are also forms )

i tried to increment the count

and further i want to show search result in budget accomdation transist form and submit the data to mysql.
this all must happen in clean manner is it possible or i must do this in reactjs

https://codepen.io/praveenshivashakti/pen/YzKoaye

```
<h2>DAy 1</h2>
<div class="job-content">
  <form class="form1">
  search: <input type="text" name="search"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Dest name: <input type="text" name="destname"><br>
  Agent name: <input type="text" name="agname"><br>
  other details: <input type="text" name="ot">
  <input type="Button" value="Budget" name="company" class="fClick" />
  <input type="button" value="Accomdation" name="course" class="xClick" />
  <input type="button" value="Transist" name="date" class="rClick" />
</form>
</div>

<h1><a href="add-new-form">ADD New Day </a></h1>






$(function () {
    var duplicates = 0,
        $original = $('.job-content').clone(true,true);

    function DuplicateForm () {
        var newForm;

        duplicates++; 

        newForm = $original.clone(true).insertBefore($('h1'));

        $.each($('input', newForm), function(i, item) {            
            $(item).attr('class', $(item).attr('class') + duplicates);
        });

        $('<h2>Day  ' + (duplicates + 1) + '</h2>').insertBefore(newForm);
    }

    $('a[href="add-new-form"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        DuplicateForm();
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.fClick', function(){ 
    alert("hey!");
}); 
 $(document).on('click', '.xClick', function(){ 
    alert("hey22!");
}); 
 $(document).on('click', '.rClick', function(){ 
    alert("hey33!");
}); 
});
```

I want every button trigger separate event that i can do but i need any automated process to do this like i do not want to sit

```
$(document).on('click', '.fClick', function(){ 
    alert("hey!");
});
```

doing like this to every button because i have a single page which generates 100 forms may be before submitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can attach the event to all classes beginning with one similar name

```
$(document).on("click", "[class*='rClick']", function() { 
    console.log("hey 3");
});
```